# Is there a way to quickly switch weapons in Max Payne 3?

Tags: max-payne-3

Sometimes I will be holding a shotgun/rifle and then it will break to a cut-scene. After the cut-scene completes there will be a lot of enemies but I will now be equipped with a pistol and the shotgun is strangely be dragged around in my other hand.

Is there a way to quickly switch back to the shotgun instead of having to bring up the radial dial? I am playing on the Xbox 360, so please indicate if you can only do it on the PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method to change weapons on the Xbox 360 version is using the radial dial, by holding the <kbd>LB</kbd> and using the right-stick to select your weapon.

My opinion, is that this can be a really fast method of selecting the weapon you want. Granted, the game goes through an animation of switching out the weapon, but as long as you know what you want, you can quickly hit both and have a weapon switched out in no time at all. Hardly what I would call cumbersome, but just my opinion.

Comment: I find it a bit cumbersome when under fire and you try to change too quickly and nothing happens. It seems like there is a bit of timing involved to let the dial briefly come up and then select it.